# ReactJS: Объясните запись {...this.props}

Tags: reactjs

Пример использования (кнопка вызова модального окна):

```
var Example = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    //var modal=...
    return (
      <div className="example">
        //{modal}
        <BootstrapButton onClick={this.openModal} className="btn-default">
          Open modal
        </BootstrapButton>
      </div>
    );
  },
  openModal: function() {
    // action...
  }
});

var BootstrapButton = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <a {...this.props}
        href="javascript:;"
        role="button"
        className={(this.props.className || '') + ' btn'} />
    );
  }

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Смысл этой записи прост: "пробрось все `props` этого компонента в дочерний компонент".

Этот синтаксис называется `spread operator`.
В JSX он работает по аналогии с "новым javascript", [ecmascript-2015](http://es6-features.org/#SpreadOperator), где этот синтаксис введен для массивов: итерируемая коллекция идущая после троеточия заменяется на последовательность элементов этой коллекции.

Ну и да, разумеется в официальной документации [есть раздел отвечающий на этот вопрос.](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-spread.html)

Comment: В данном вопросе, вы немного, ошиблись, поскольку этот "сахар", в примере кода, применяется к HTML тегу а не компоненту. Но примирительно к компоненам, вы все правильно сказали.

Answer (score 2):

Копирует содержимое объекта this.props текущего компонента, и вставляет их в качестве атрибутов в указанный тег, используя имя свойства как имя атрибута, а его значение, соответственно как значение атрибута.

Судя по всему, это проявление новомодных веяний  стандарта ECMAScript 2015